# I have multiple functions with the same code apart from the numbers in an array. Could this code be DRY-er?

Tags: javascript

I'm basically building this slide show that has clickable buttons on the bottom that allows you to navigate through the slides. The BG, the block quote and a little border on the button are the things that change as I cycle through the slides.

I've written some code to do this, but it's not very dry and it bothers me. I have 6 separate functions that basically run through numbers in an array and I was wondering if there was a way to make this code a bit cleaner and dry. Any idea what I could do to improve that?

```js
var quotes = document.querySelectorAll(".quote"),
  slideBg = document.querySelectorAll(".quote-img"),
  slideBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".selector"),
  headline = document.querySelector("#quote-head");

//   --------------reset-----------------
function reset() {
  for (var i = 0; i < quotes.length; i++) {
    quotes[i].classList.remove("show");
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < slideBg.length; i++) {
    slideBg[i].classList.remove("show");
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < slideBtn.length; i++) {
    slideBtn[i].classList.remove("active");
  }
  headline.classList.add("centralize");
}

// ----------------Buttons---------------
function quote1() {
  reset();
  quotes[0].classList.add("show");
  slideBg[0].classList.add("show");
  slideBtn[0].classList.add("active");
  headline.classList.remove("centralize");
}
function quote2() {
  reset();
  quotes[1].classList.add("show");
  slideBg[1].classList.add("show");
  slideBtn[1].classList.add("active");
  headline.classList.remove("centralize");
}
function quote3() {
  reset();
  quotes[2].classList.add("show");
  slideBg[2].classList.add("show");
  slideBtn[2].classList.add("active");
  headline.classList.remove("centralize");
}
function quote4() {
  reset();
  quotes[3].classList.add("show");
  slideBg[3].classList.add("show");
  slideBtn[3].classList.add("active");
  headline.classList.remove("centralize");
}
function quote5() {
  reset();
  quotes[4].classList.add("show");
  slideBg[4].classList.add("show");
  slideBtn[4].classList.add("active");
  headline.classList.remove("centralize");
}
function quote6() {
  reset();
  quotes[5].classList.add("show");
  slideBg[5].classList.add("show");
  slideBtn[5].classList.add("active");
  headline.classList.remove("centralize");
}

// init
quote1();
```

Also, Image for a more visual reference:
[image]

I wanted to make it scroll through automatically as well, so having 1 line of code that allows me to run through the array would be amazing.

Comment: Pass the index as a parameter to a generic `quote` function. `function quote(index) { reset();
  quotes[index].classList.add("show"); ... etc }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can minimise your code like this:

```
var quotes = document.querySelectorAll(".quote"),
slideBg = document.querySelectorAll(".quote-img"),
slideBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".selector"),
headline = document.querySelector("#quote-head");

//   --------------reset-----------------
function reset() {
    quotes.forEach((elem) => elem.classList.remove("show"));
    slideBg.forEach((elem) => elem.classList.remove("show"));
    slideBtn.forEach((elem) => elem.classList.remove("active"));
    headline.classList.add("centralize");
}

// ----------------Buttons---------------
function quote(index) {
  reset();
  quotes[index].classList.add("show");
  slideBg[index].classList.add("show");
  slideBtn[index].classList.add("active");
  headline.classList.remove("centralize");
}

// init
quote(index);
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I tried this, but now the buttons stop working entirely and I get this on the console:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined"

I'm completely new to JS. I should've probably added that at the top. Apologies if this is a bit of a silly response.

Comment: I am very sorry for a silly typo. I have wrote "ele" in place of "elem" in the forEach loops. Please refer to the corrected code.

Comment: Disregard! I just figured it out. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Since your function does exactly the same why not simply pass it a parameter.
So instead of calling **quote5();** call **quote(4);**.

```
function quote(param) {
  reset();
  quotes[param].classList.add("show");
  slideBg[param].classList.add("show");
  slideBtn[param].classList.add("active");
  headline.classList.remove("centralize");
}
```